# Get event from getfeedback.com on Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I'm trying to implement a survey from [this](https://www.getfeedback.com/) site on my app.

According to the [docs](https://community.getfeedback.com/s/article/Embedding-a-survey-in-your-iOS-and-Android-mobile-app) in order to get foucs back to your app you have to open the url on a webview (which is working fine) and also inject an object of type `window.messageHandler` to it.

> Web views need to inject a window.messageHandler object with a postMessage function. For example:
>
> ```
> window.messageHandler = {
>
>   postMessage: function(message) { doSomethingInMyApp(message); }
>
> }
> ```

After some research I found that you can inject JavaScript objects into a webview using [@JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface), so I took a free trial on the site and created a survey and a simple activity with a webview that points to said survey:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var webView: WebView? = null

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

        webView?.let {
            it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            it.addJavascriptInterface(JsObject(this), "window.messageHandler")
            it.loadUrl("https://www.getfeedback.com/r/JgP2hwlZ")
        }
    }

    class JsObject(private val context: Context) {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun postMessage(message: String) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Something happened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't get the method `postMessage` to execute, any ideas?

I also already tried to pass `messageHandler` as the name in `addJavascriptInterface` but doesn't work either. Interestingly this ends up in the survey throwing an error message saying that my response couldn't be sent. This only happens if I pass `messageHandler` as the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself:

First you have to use `addJavascriptInterface()` to inject your object and then use `webView.evaluateJavaScript()` to inject the script into the page inside of which you also pass your `JavascriptInterface` object and call to its own method. Note that `evaluateJavascript()` needs to be called after the page has finished loading, otherwise it won't work. This essentially sets a listener that will be triggered after the survey is done, which will result in a call to you object's method.

Put all this together and you'll have something like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var webView: WebView? = null

    companion object {
        private const val SCRIPT =
            "window.messageHandler = { postMessage: function(message) { object.doSomethingInMyApp(message); } }"
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

        webView?.let {
            it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            it.addJavascriptInterface(JsObject(this), "object")
            it.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                    webView?.evaluateJavascript(SCRIPT, null)
                }
            }
            it.loadUrl("https://www.getfeedback.com/r/JgP2hwlZ")
        }
    }

    class JsObject(private val context: Context) {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun doSomethingInMyApp(message: String) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Something happened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```